# Debian apt issue (not found and deb12u1)

Tags: debian, apt, gnome

I wanted to install texmaker the other day but I ran into an issue : it downloaded 500mb but it told me it could not find a few dependencies, for instance

`Err : 4 http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/texlive-bin/texlive-binaries_2022.20220321.62855-5.1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP : .... 80]`

I looked it up on the repo, it was there with a different name :
http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/texlive-bin/texlive-binaries_2022.20220321.62855-5.1+deb12u1_amd64.deb

The error suggested that i run the command with `--fix-missing` and run `apt update` before, but it didnt work. So i tried to download the file and install it with `sudo apt install ./texlive-binaries...+deb12u1_amd64.deb`. Then running `sudo apt install texmaker` still did not found the package as it recognized the version is `5.1+deb12u1_amd64` and not `5.1`. I looked it up on google, did not find much, and moved on Overleaf.

But today, i ran `apt update && apt upgrade`, and after i reboot i come to a tty. I am surprised. I found out i can't start gnome with `startx` or `sudo systemctl enable gdm3`. It turns out apt updated `gnome-shell-common` to a `deb12u1_amd64` version, and it broke the DE.

Now `apt` lists all the gnome packets as installed automatically and not needed anymore, aswell as `bolt, gir1, ibus, ...`

I am confused, when i run `apt install gdm3` it tells me `gnome-shell` depends on `gnome-shell-common = 43.4-1 but 43.6-1~deb12u1 will be installed. Impossible to fix the problem.`

I looked up `/etc/apt/sources.list` but everything seems fine :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm flags
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm flags

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security flags
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security flags

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates flags
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates flags
```

where `flags` is `main non-free-firmware non-free contrib`. Also in `source.list.d` I have `vscodium.list` which contains `deb [singed-by = /usr/share...gpg ] https://download.vscodium.con/debs vscodium main`

`apt policy gnome gnome-shell` returns

```
gnome:
  installed : none
  candidate : 1:43+1
  version table :
    1:43+1 500
    500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
gnome-shell:
  installed : none
  candidate :43.4-1
  version table :
    43.4-1 500
    500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Here is the content of `apt update` :

```
Reached :1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Reached :2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Reached :3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Reached :4 http://download.vscodium.com/debs vscodium InRelease
Reading list ... done
Constructing dependency tree ... done
Reading information status ... done
1 packet can be updated. Run apt list --upgradable to see it
```

Now I have a new update which is `nvidia-installer-cleanup` and `apt policy nvidia-installer=cleanup` is :

```
nvidia-installer-cleanup:
  installed : 20220217+2
  candidate : 20220217+3~deb12u1
  version table :
    20220217+3~deb12u1 500
      500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/contrib amd64 Packages
    20220217+2 100 
      100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

But i think i found the issue. I have a Brother HL-2135W printer that used to work on Debian 11. However, this time it did not work out of the box so when i tried to install it with the script found on Brother's support website, it was a 32 bit script : https://www.brother.fr/services-et-supports/hl-2135w/downloads

The script messed up `libc6-i386`. I had to run `dpkg -add-architecture i386` which messed up `apt`. `dpkg -l | grep i386` outputs

```
cupswrapperhl2130:i386
hl2130lpr:i386
```

so I uninstalled those two packages and run `dpkg --remove-architecture i386`. But I still can't install gnome. There is a deeper issue with apt probably.

I run Debian 12 bookworm on an Dell Inspiron 5415 with Ryzen 5 5500U.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: deb12u1 means that it’s [the first post-release update for Debian 12](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622326/86440). It’s usually a good idea to install those versions ;-). Does it help if you run `rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*.debian.org.*` and then `apt update`? (And check `apt policy gnome-shell` after that — it should show 43.6-1~deb12u1.)

Comment: Flushing `/var/lib/apt/lists/*.debian.org_*` did the work, then i ran `apt update` and i was able to reinstall gdm3, thank you very much for your help :)
how do i mark the post as resolved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the local cache of repository information on your system is outdated, and `apt update` isn’t updating it. To fix that, delete the local cache:

```
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*.debian.org_*
```

and then run

```
apt update
```

again (both as root).